# Functions sets innerHTML to null

Tags: javascript

I want the image to change when I click on it

I tried to build a function that gets the ID of the item I clicked and on tries to replace the image with its ID.

`onclick='M(this);`

```
function M(currentThis) {
    if (redTurn == false) {
        document.getElementById(currentThis).innerHTML = "<img src=" + images[1] + " style='width:60px; height:60px' />";
    }
}
```

The innerHtmL sets to null but it should get the ID of the item.

Comment: because `this` has nothing to do with an id string. (It would help to see the actual code)

Comment: Just do `currentThis.innerHTML = ..`

Comment: STOP USING INNERHTML... This has unintended side effects, and is a horrible way to go about appending HTML elements to your application. You're just making the browser do even more work by making it parse more HTML, vs creating nodes in memory and appending them to the parent node.

Comment: what is the value of `images[1]`, if it is a path to an item, you should wrap it in `'` apostrophes when settings the `src` attribute.

Comment: @ndugger ?? there's nothing wrong with using `.innerHTML`. I use it extensively and exclusively in many web applications and I have absolutely no performance problems. That advice made some sense 12 or 13 years ago but modern browsers are vastly better at dealing with it.

Comment: @Pointy The side effects are not all performance related. While you may not have problems, it does still create overhead. I'd be more concerned about security implications from concatenating strings of HTML and the unforseen side effects of wiping event listeners on elements whose innerHTML you directly modify.

Comment: @ndugger well certainly, but in my case at least the markup is all generated by a templating system (like what React or Angular use) and there are provisions for HTML-escaping user-origin content, and so on. I think most modern frameworks use `.innerHTML` with wild abandon, honestly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try those

```
function M(currentThis) {
    if (redTurn == false) {
        currentThis.innerHTML = "<img src=" + images[1] + " style='width:60px; height:60px' />";
    }
}
```

or

```
onclick="M(this.id);"

function M(currentThis) {
    if (redTurn == false) {
        document.getElementById(currentThis).innerHTML = "<img src=" + images[1] + " style='width:60px; height:60px' />";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
function M(currentThis) {
  if (redTurn == false) {
    document.getElementById(currentThis.target.id).innerHTML = "<img src=" + images[1] + " 
       style='width:60px; height:60px' />";
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you have a reference to an element and then use it to look itself up again? :) And you are saying `currentThis` is the event object, but it is showing passing in `this`

Comment: Oh my bad if this is the case then use currentThis.id and let me know if it helps